# Save table with data to file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file, html-table

I'm doing search which suits some conditions, for example special year. I'm using MongoDB, Express.js and Node.js. Here is a bit of my code:

```
***table.ejs***
    <%yearOfsyllabusList.forEach(syllabus => {%>
      <div class="container fixTable">
        <main>
          <div class="row ">
            <table class="table" border="2">
              <div class="row">
              <thead class="table-primary">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Year</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Additional info</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr class="table-info">
                    <!-- <th scope="row">1</th> -->
                    <td><%= syllabus.yearOfsyl %></td>
                    <td><%= syllabus.nameOfsyl %></td>
                    <td><%= syllabus.syllabusInfo %></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                </div>
              </table>
            </div>
          </main>
    </div>
<%})%>
```

Here I do search using my Syllabus schema and then I display results in table(table.ejs upper).

```
function getSyllabusesYear(req, res, next){
  Syllabus.find({}, function(err, yearsOfsyllabus){
    if (err) throw err;
     res.locals.yearsOfsyllabusList = [];
     next();
  })
}

function postSyllabusesYear(req, res, next){
  const Year = req.body.yearCheck;
  Syllabus.find({
    yearOfsyl: Year
  }, function(err, yearsOfsyllabus){
    if (err) next(err);
     res.locals.yearsOfsyllabusList = yearsOfsyllabus;
     next();
  });
}
```

I want to save data which I receive in table to file. I was looking for any information over the Internet, but I don't find the appropriate answer. Maybe, I should try using fs or something like that. Can you give me any suggestion or some piece of advice or maybe some modifications to my code?

Comment: to save to a file: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

Comment: yeah, i have visited this site, but how can i use this according to my example?

Comment: get data from mongoDB (i believe you've covered this); JSON.stringify the data and save to file (w3schools link above)